# Method takes another object as a parameter

Tags: java, object, parameters, distance, points

I am doing homework for java programming. I am asked to write a method that returns a distance between two points.  I should use given formula that `distance = square root((x2 - x1)*(x2 - x1) +(y2 - y1)*(y2 - y1))`.

In the below codes, an object `a` will be contained current coordinate x1 and y1 and `b` will be coordinate x2 and y2, passed to move at some where.

How can I write the method in this class without having other classes and other elements such as x2, y2?  In the objects there are two values but how can I assign each to x1 and x2, and y1 and y2?  I found definition of vector for java but I am not sure it is applicable for this.  Does anybody have an idea?

```
public class MyPoint{
    private int x;
    private int y;
}

public MyPoint(int x, int y){
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
} 

public int distanceTo(MyPoint a, MyPoint b){
    MyPoint.x1 = a;
    MyPoint.y1 = a;
    MyPoint.x2 = b;
    MyPoint.y2 = b;
    double distance = Math.sqrt((x2-x1)*(x2-x1) + (y2-y1)*(y2-y1));
    return distance;
}
}
```

Comment: Queens College, Landau's into to Java course?

Comment: Off topic: use `Math.pow(x2-x1,2)` instead of `(x2-x1)*(x2-x1)`. In general, when you have to do a power, use `Math.pow(expression, power)`

Comment: @BackSlash: off topic, but if he's doing a lot of calculations, the code as written, `(x2-x1)*(x2-x1)`, is better than using Math.pow. You should profile this to see why.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The distanceTo method should only take one parameter, a MyPoint object, not two parameters:

```
public double distanceTo(MyPoint other) {
  // ...
}
```

The first object of the comparison will be the current object, the one whose method is being called.

Then in the method body you compare the current object's fields, the `this.x` and `this.y` with the x and y values of the object passed in to the method's parameter, `other.x` and `other.y`.

Also, the method probably should return a double, not an int as you have it defined.

Regarding,

> How can I write the method in this class without having other classes and other elements such as x2, y2?

I'm not sure exactly what you mean by this.

Comment: @Hovercreaft: Thank you for your answer.  Using one parameter I haven't thought about it but it does make sense.  By the way let me clarify the question you didn't get it.

Comment: I referred this webpage following.  http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/objects.html  It explains well method takes an object as parameter though it has three java files.  I needed to put all in one java file.  That is what I tried to say so.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to declare MyPoint.x1 = a. That isn't really doing anything. Instead you can reference the points such as `a.x` or `b.y`.

Additionally you should make sure that your return type is what you want.

EDIT: Hovercraft has essentially said the same as I did but a little nicer.

Comment: @ Vnquish46: Thanks for the input.  I keep that it mine.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Point
{
    int x,y;

    public Point(int x, int y)
    {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }
    public static double distance(Point a, Point b)
    {
        return Math.sqrt((a.x-b.x)*(a.x-b.x)+(a.y-b.y)*(a.y-b.y));
    }
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Point a = new Point(0,0);
        Point b = new Point(3,5);
        System.out.println(distance(a,b));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the full codes.  It emitted compile errors "cannot find symbol" though I got hint from your code to solve the issue.  I appreciate it!